# python error message when loading pickle file

Tags: python, nlp

I have the below code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import re
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import sklearn.metrics as metrics
import pickle

#%matplotlib inline
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

stemmer = PorterStemmer()
words = stopwords.words("english")

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer_tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english', max_df=0.7)

# call and load pickle here
content = pickle.load(open("vectorizer.pk",'rb'))

vectorizer_tfidf = [vectorizer_tfidf]
test_tfIdf = vectorizer_tfidf.transform('processedtext')
test_tfIdf2 = vectorizer_tfidf.transform('processedtext2')

testdata = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\joyce\\Desktop\\CR_Summary 08052020.csv', delimiter = ',')
content = pickle.load(open("Pickle_RL_Model.pkl",'rb'))
 
##print (content)    
testdata=testdata.fillna(value='test')

#Array to return prediction
content.predict(testdata)
```

Error Message:

> File "C:/Users/joyce/nltk CR data v3.py", line 42, in 
> test_tfIdf = vectorizer_tfidf.transform('processedtext')
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'transform'

How do I correct this error?

Comment: `vectorizer_tfidf = [vectorizer_tfidf]` this line (line 40) creates `List` called `vectorizer_tfidf`. Get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

*Error means*: **transform** function cannot be applied to a list .
In your case ***vectorizer_tfid*** is a list , thats why an error is shown.

```
vectorizer_tfidf = [vectorizer_tfidf]
```

This line creates the list.
Try removing it.

Comment: Error:File "C:\Users\joyce\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 1103, in transform
    "Iterable over raw text documents expected, "

ValueError: Iterable over raw text documents expected, string object received.

Comment: the string is "processedtext" , which the function is not expecting.What are processedtext and processedtext2.

Comment: dataset['processedtext'] = dataset['SUMMARY'].apply(lambda x: " ".join([stemmer.stem(i) for i in re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", str(x)).split() if i not in words]).lower())
dataset['processedtext2'] = dataset['Details'].apply(lambda x: " ".join([stemmer.stem(i) for i in re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", str(x)).split() if i not in words]).lower())

Comment: i can send the py file to you if you want , where i built the pickle file

Comment: Please refer my posted answer, in the doc link you will find the correct usage of transform() function. You are passing 'str' it accepts an iterable object like a list.
Here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.transform

Comment: You are passing a string in **transform()** method. You have to pass a list in the transform function. Your first error was due to `list.transform()`. Now your error is due to `transform(string)`

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) and you will see that you are calling ***transform()*** method on a **list** object which doesn't support it. Please visit
to [sklearn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.transform) to know more about the correct usage.

Minimally, you can remove this call:

```
vectorizer_tfidf = [vectorizer_tfidf]
```